# Parse JSON data in JSON params in Python

Tags: python, json

Is it possible to load json with json data inside?

```
import json
array = '{"container":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}'
data  = json.loads(array)
print(data['container'])
```

in this code error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 17 (char 16)

Comment: what do you mean _json with json data inside_? Json by definition contains _json_ data. The problem you have is because of _incorrect json_. There are "\" characters placed at disallowed locations.

Comment: or simply use another array (dict) inside your array

Comment: This will work: `array = '{"container": {"foo": "bar"}}'`

Comment: @BlueRineS The backslashes are absolutely allowed, they're stripped by Python. And I believe "json with json data inside" means a JSON-encoded string, containing as a value another JSON-encoded string.

Comment: thanks, but this json not from python, it comes otside from js, and i don't able to edit this format.  Python's parser can't read this format json?

Comment: If it does come from outside like that, it won't be represented like that in Python. Proof: There's no backslashes in the output of `print('{"container":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}')`. So the question is _how_ is this data coming to your Python code.

Comment: it comes from hikvision site after authorization, JSON  has that format. Maybe the solution is:   replace \"  to  "  after get JSON  and before "json.loads" and everything will be fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implementation works for me with Python3.6.6.

**Code:**

```
import json
array = '{"container":{"foo":"bar"}}'
data = json.loads(array)
print(data['container'])
print(data['container']['foo'])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
{'foo': 'bar'}
bar
```

**NOTE:** If you use the comas around in nested Json then the value of `container` key will be a string not a `dict` type (after parsing).

Let's see:

**Code:**

```
import json
array = '{"container":"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"}'
data = json.loads(array)
print(data['container'])
print(data['container']['foo'])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
{"foo":"bar"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(data['container']['foo'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

If you really want to use the comas, you need to parse again the nested Json.

Like this:

**Code:**

```
import json
array = '{"container":"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"}'
data = json.loads(array)
print(data['container'])
data2 = json.loads(data['container'])
print(data2['foo'])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
{"foo":"bar"}
bar
```

Comment: thanks, but this json not from python, it comes otside from js, and i don't able to edit this format.

Comment: I understand but it doesn't matter that where Json comes from. If you check my last code, you can see it does exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need more escaping:

```
import json
array = '{"container":"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"}'
data = json.loads(array)
print(data['container'])
```

The problem here was that even in single quoted strings, `\"` is an escape sequence for a single quote. The backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash to avoid that.

Comment: if you are changing the json source anyway, why not change it directly to another dictionary, rather than a string representing one?

Comment: Because the OP asked about JSON containing JSON, not simply nested JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import ast
array = '{"container":"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"}'

json_data = ast.literal_eval(array)

print(json_data['container'])
```

the output will be  `{'foo':'bar'}`